# Shortest script that gives the time passed since a Unix timestamp

Tags: code-golf, date

What you need to do to win this challenge is to write the shortest "timeago" script that outputs the number of decades, years, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds between a given [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and the time the script is run.

You must give the time difference in "lowest terms", e.g. `1 week` not `7 days`, `9 years` not `0 decades 9 years`. You also must use plural forms correctly, e.g. `1 day` not `1 days`.

Your script must be accurate to within plus or minus 1 second (so the exact second rounding method is unimportant).

```
Time Equivalency Table
1 decade = 10 years
1 year = 31536000 seconds (not technically correct but close enough)
1 week = 7 days
1 day = 24 hours
1 hour = 60 minutes
1 minute = 60 seconds
```

The output should be of the form

```
A decade(s) B year(s) C week(s) D day(s) E hour(s) F minute(s) G second(s)
```

where `A...G` are all non-negative integers and the `s` is only there for plurals.

## Notes

- The timestamp will always be a time from the past. **It may be negative.**
- Input and output may be anything reasonable: stdin/stdout, function input and return value, etc.
- You may not use any tools that already do this. i.e. if your language has a `timesince(timestamp)` function built in you may not use that function.

*I have vastly edited this to make it clearer in hopes to assuage the somewhat silly battle between new users with unclear questions and old users who require perfection. It was not a terrible question (though now it may be too similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/the-time-traveler)).*

Given that enough time is passed since the last answer, I declare **Three If By Whiskey** with its *177 bytes* Ruby implementation the winner of this context!

Comment: So it has to be JavaScript? If not, where do the times come from?

Comment: "In the case of Javascript JQuery is forbidden :P Everything else is ok." -- is [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) allowed, then?

Comment: The spec is kinda poor. Please provide an exact definition of what it is supposed to do - an example implementation doesn't suffice.

Comment: Is Timeago some new scripting language? Is updating every 30 seconds optional (as stated in one place) or a requirement (as stated in another)? What I/O mechanisms are acceptable? What rounding should be used? In particular, how does rounding interact with variable-length time periods such as calendar months and years? Some of these may imply follow-up questions depending on your answers.

Comment: Your title made me want to find out more, what was the task before it was removed?  And why does this restore of a backup have auto-correct, when the backup didn't o.0

Comment: @PopeyGilbert It doesn't seem to be something interesting anyway. The task was to create the shortest "timeago" script ;) Should I revert?

Comment: Ah no, don't worry.  I have this avid need to know things that I can't find out.  Once I can find them out it becomes less interesting =).

Comment: @PopeyGilbert No problem, you're welcome :) And I'm like that too :p

Comment: @Abdossam The issue is that the question was unclear. You never mentioned that 1408813114 was a _Unix_ timestamp, something not everyone would pick up on. You also never specified the output format. Should we say `1 hour 7 days ago` or `1 hour 1 week ago`? That is why it is being voted down and closed, but it could still be salvaged.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Thank you for the comment. I made it clearer by specifying the output format and what an Unix timestamp is with a link to Wikipedia, can you tell if it's any better?

Comment: Ok, another downvote. I fixed what I had to fix, what else is to be fixed guys? I'm nearly banging my head on the wall because I can't understand where it's wrong at this point

Comment: What exact units are used and what's the granularity? e.g. will month be used? year, decade, century, etc.? Do you allow negative timestamps? (I'd suggest not using month since it's variable.) What about I/O: stdin/stdout? (See PeterTaylor's comment above.)

Comment: The title sounds like Timeago is some new programming language. I'd suggest something like "Shortest script that prints the time passed since a Unix timestamp"

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies The granularity is like the following: If less than a minute is passed since, it will be displayed as **num** seconds ago, if less than a hour is passed **num** minutes ago and so on. This means that even if **1 hour and 5 minutes** is passed since it will be just displayed as **1 hour**. As I said I/O is not important as long as it doesn't impacts the size of the final code. Why is there so much concern about I/O for this script? Is there something I missed? I changed the title now :)

Comment: I think this task might be challenging. But please, give a complete list of units and example output! (Do you expect years, months, weeks?)

Comment: This is code-golf. So of course I/O matters and impacts the final code length. ```print n``` is shorter than ```return n```.

Comment: @Abdossam I know we all seem pretty fussy but it's because questions on this site are supposed to have objective winning criteria _and_ [a clear spec](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Abdossam Didn't notice that you said all I/O was ok but it should say so in the question.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Updated the question. I understand your motivations :)

Comment: @Falko I've updated the question to reflect your comment and added context. So, *as long as it accomplishes the goal and doesn't impact the size of the final code* you're good to go!

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Leave out the HTML part. I guess nobody want's to write an HTML parser before being able to tackle the real task of printing times. 2) Make clear that you restrict to "second(s)", "minute(s)", "hour(s)" and "day(s)". You might add "week(s)" if you wish. But months and years are not that clearly defined (28-31 days / 365 or 366 days...). This should fix the major concerns with this question in my point of view.

Comment: Why didn't the shortest solution get accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ruby, <s>184</s> 177

```
->n{x=Time.now.to_i-n;d=[3650*y=86400,365*y,7*y,y,3600,60,1];(0..6).map{|i|c=x/d[i];(x%=d[i]*c;"#{c} #{%w[decade year week day hour minute second][i]}#{c<2?'':'s'}")if c>0}*' '}
```

There's nothing particularly clever here, but I suspect it's still very close to optimal.

**Example run**

```
p ->n{x=Time.now.to_i-n;d=[3650*y=86400,365*y,7*y,y,3600,60,1];(0..6).map{|i|c=x/d[i];(x%=d[i]*c;"#{c} #{%w[decade year week day hour minute second][i]}#{c<2?'':'s'}")if c>0}*' '}[0]
"4 decades 4 years 41 weeks 3 days 14 hours 20 minutes 48 seconds"
```

Answer (score 2):

### J , 165

```
;' '&,@":&.>@((#~([:*&>{."1))@((;:' decades years weeks days hours minutes seconds')(],.([}.~[:-1=])&.>)<"0@(_ 10 52 7 24 60 60&#:)@(-~([:".@}:[:2!:0'date +%s'"_))))
```

Can probably be golfed more. Uses a shell call to date for getting the current unix epoch time, since Unix epoch is unavailable in J.

Example run:

```
;' '&,@":&.>@((#~([:*&>{."1))@((;:' decades years weeks days hours minutes seconds')(],.([}.~[:-1=])&.>)<"0@(_ 10 52 7 24 60 60&#:)@(-~([:".@}:[:2!:0'date +%s'"_)))) 0
4 decades 4 years 41 weeks 3 days 12 hours 54 minutes 1 second
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 183

```
import time;t=int(time.time()-input());d=86400
for f,u in zip((3650*d,365*d,7*d,d,3600,60,1),'decade year week day hour minute second'.split()):
 if t/f:print`t/f`,u+'s'*(t/f>1),;t%=f
```

Output for a timestamp 999996400 seconds in the past:

```
3 decades 1 year 37 weeks 46 minutes 39 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 287

```
function p(e,n){return e>2?e+" "+n+"s ":e+" "+n+" "}function t(e){n=new Date/1e3,l=e-n,c=1,m=60,h=60*m,d=24*h,w=7*d,y=365*d,a=10*y,s="",v={a:"Decade",y:"Year",w:"Week",d:"Day",h:"Hour",m:"Minute",c:"Second"};for(i in v)k=v[i],i=window[i],(r=Math.floor(l/i))>0&&(s+=p(r,k)),l%=i;alert(s)}
```

to run use `t(secondsInFuture)`;

Comment: When I run `t(10)` I just get an empty `alert`.

Comment: Ugh, forgot the seconds, thanks @IngoBürk. To be clear its `t(new Date()/1000 + 10);`

Comment: Use ES6's fat arrow notation, also `eval(i)` is 2 bytes shorter than `window[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 392

```javascript
t=function(c){i=function(){var a=+new Date/1e3-c,b=document;29>a?b.write("just now"):60>a?b.write((a|0)+" seconds ago"):60<a&&120>a?b.write("1 minute ago"):60>a/60?b.write((a/60|0)+" minutes ago"):60<a/60&&120>a/60?b.write("1 hour ago"):24>a/3600?b.write((a/3600|0)+" hours ago"):24<a/3600&&48>a/3600?b.write("1 day ago"):1<=a/86400&&b.write((a/86400|0)+" days ago")};i();setInterval(i,3e4)};
```

*Also the unminified code for the curious ones*

```javascript
t = function(timestamp){

i = function() {
var diff = (+new Date/1e3)-(timestamp),
d = document;

    if( (diff) < 29) {

        d.write( 'just now' )
    }
    else if( diff < 60) {

        d.write( ( (diff) |0 ) + ' seconds ago' )
    }
    else if( diff > 60 && diff < 120) {
        d.write(  '1 minute ago' )
    }
    else if( (diff)/60 < 60) {
        d.write( ( (diff)/60 |0 ) + ' minutes ago' )
    }
    else if( (diff)/60 > 60 && (diff)/60 < 120) {
        d.write( '1 hour ago' )
    }
    else if( (diff)/3600 < 24) {
        d.write( ( (diff)/3600 |0 ) + ' hours ago' )
    }
    else if( (diff)/3600 > 24 && (diff)/3600 < 48) {
        d.write( '1 day ago' )
    }
    else if( (diff)/86400 >= 1) {
        d.write( ( (diff)/86400 |0 ) + ' days ago' )
    }
  }

i()

setInterval(i, 3e4)

}
```

It updates every 30 seconds and calculates both singular and plural.

To run it use `t(unix_timestamp)`

Comment: Shouldn't you use fat arrow notation?

Comment: @user965091 Please avoid throwing around accusations without any proof via public comments on unrelated posts; if you think someone is using a sock account, flag a post of theirs for moderator attention. I see absolutely no reason to suspect any sockpuppetry here, and even if there was, such a discussion should not be had in public.

Comment: @user965091 I don't see how any of the comments here could be considered "provocations." In any case, [**rudeness is not tolerated** on the Stack Exchange network](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Please try to remain courteous to *all* users, regardless of whether you suspect they are breaking the rules or for any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 263

```
i=[315360000,31536000,604800,86400,3600,60,1];s=['decade','year','week','day','hour','minute','second'];function g(d){return p(parseInt((new Date().getTime()-d)/1000), 0);}function p(d,n){k=d-d%i[n];r=k/i[n];return (r>0?r+' '+s[n]+'(s) ':'')+(n<6?p(d-k,n+1):'');}
```

to run from the Javascript console, call

```
g(unixTimestamp);
```