# How long ago was this?

Tags: code-golf, date

### The Rules

- Each submission must be a full program.
- The program must take input as two comma-separated dates in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`, and print the number of days that has passed since the second date to STDOUT as if today was the first date (if the second date would be in the future, output a negative number) plus an optional trailing newline, and nothing else. Assume both dates are in the Gregorian calendar.
- The program must not write anything to STDERR.

  Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested.
- Submissions are scored in *bytes*, in an appropriate (pre-existing) encoding, usually (but not necessarily) UTF-8. Some languages, like [Folders](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Folders), are a bit tricky to score - if in doubt, please ask on [Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins

### Examples

**Input:**

```
2015-12-03,2015-12-01
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

**Input:**

```
2015-12-03,2014-12-01
```

**Output:**

```
367
```

**Input:**

```
2015-12-03,2013-12-03
```

**Output:**

```
730
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36697/36670)

Comment: Are we allowed to use external libraries? Ones that are common in a given ecosystem but are not part of the standard lib? (For example, no one uses the JDK's Date APIs but JodaTime instead, even though it is technically an external library).

Comment: I assume everything uses UTC, since in my timezone the difference between 2015-11-01T00:00:00 and 2015-11-02T00:00:00 was only ~0.96 days (23 hours) due to daylight savings. You didn't mention anything about rounding fractional days, so you might want to clarify this in the question. (I think a lot of datetime libraries default to using local time.)

Comment: What is the case for leap years?

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup they must be handled

Comment: Why the specific and awkward input format?

Comment: How is it awkward? It is standard date format  seperated by commas.. @Adám

Comment: @ev3commander Using commas to separate is very artificial for array languages. Is this a parsing challenge or a calculation challenge?

Comment: What if my language doesn't support reading date from the system? Can I take it from stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 24 bytes

```
((a=D.parse)×-a(y©/864e5
```

Uses `Date.parse` to parse the date, then get's the difference and divides.

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22((a%3DD.parse)(x)-a(y))%2F864e5%22&inputs=%5B%222015-12-03,2015-12-01%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:true,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

### Explanation && Ungolfed

```
((a=D.parse)(x)-a(y))/864e5

               // Implicit: x is first date
               // y is second date
(
 (a=D.parse)   // Assign Date.parse to 'a'
 (x)           // Run Date.parse with first date
 -a(y)         // Subtract Date.parse run with second date
)/864e5        // Divide by 86,400,000
```

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 37

```bash
tr , \\n|date -f- +%s|dc -e??-86400/p
```

`tr` replaces the comma with a newline.  `date` reads the newline separated dates and outputs the number of seconds since the Unix epoch that the passed-in date represents.  These numbers are then put on the `dc` stack.  Then its a simple matter of subtraction and divide by (24*60*60).  In this case, `dc` stack-based RPN arithmetic evaluation is better than `bc` or bash `$( )`, mostly because the subraction-before-division needs no parentheses.

Input via STDIN:

```bash
$ echo 2015-12-3,2015-12-1 | ./longago.sh
2
$ echo 2015-12-3,2014-12-1 | ./longago.sh
367
$ echo 2015-12-3,2013-12-3 | ./longago.sh
730
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 67 bytes

```julia
print(Int(-diff(map(i->Date(i,"y-m-d"),split(readline(),",")))[1]))
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
# Read a line from STDIN
r = readline()

# Split it into two character dates
s = split(r, ",")

# Convert each to a Date object
d = map(i -> Date(i, "y-m-d"), s)

# Compute the difference in dates (first-second)
f = diff(d)[1]

# Convert the Base.Date.Day object to an integer
# Negate to get second-first
i = Int(-f)

# Print to STDOUT
print(i)
```

Comment: Instead of `-diff(d)[1]` you can use `-(d...)` to save a couple of bytes. What Julia version are you using by the way? On 1.2, I had to explicitly import `Dates` and I also can't just convert days to integers like this.

Comment: This answer was posted in 2015, so it was probably Julia 0.3 or 0.4 at the latest.

Answer (score 4):

### Scala, <s>166</s> <s>139</s> <s>120</s> <s>116</s> 92 bytes

```
print(args(0).replace('-','/').split(",").map(java.util.Date.parse(_)/86400000).reduce(_-_))
```

Usage: `scala [source filename].scala [date1],[date2]`

*Note: The third version (120 bytes) and on uses a deprecated API. It still compiles and works fine.*
*Note2: Thanks to the commenters below for the great advice!*

Comment: Since the trailing new line is optional you could use `print` instead of `println`.

Comment: You can remove the `Object A extends App{...}` part and save it as `a.scala` and run it with `scala a.scala 2015-12-3,2015-12-1` ;)

Comment: @MartijnR Genius! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>69</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
a=->l{Time.gm *$F[l,3]};p (a[0]-a[3]).div 86400
```

47 bytes + 8 bytes for command line option. Thanks to Dane Anderson, saved 2 bytes.

**57 bytes**

```
p (Time.gm(*$F[0,3])-Time.gm(*$F[3,3])).div 86400
```

49 bytes code + 8 bytes for command line option. Saved 8 bytes with manatwork's suggestion.

**65 bytes**

```
a,b=gets.split(?,).map{|i|Time.gm *i.split(?-)};p (a-b).div 86400
```

**66 bytes**

```
a,b=gets.split(?,).map{|i|Time.new *i.split(?-)};p (a-b).div 86400
```

**69 bytes**

```
a,b=gets.split(',').map{|i|Time.new *i.split('-')};p (a-b).to_i/86400
```

[Test it online](https://ideone.com/CiJ5Ik)

**Ungolfed**

```
a = -> l {
  Time.gm *$F[l,3]       # Anonymous method to parse time
}
p (a[0]-a[3]).div 86400  # Subtracts two times and divides by 24*60*60
```

**Usage:**

```
ruby -naF[,-] -e 'a=->l{Time.gm *$F[l,3]};p (a[0]-a[3]).div 86400' <<< '2015-12-3,2013-12-3'

=> 730
```

Comment: Three little chars: `','` → `?,`, `'-'` → `?-`, `to_i/` → `div `.

Comment: Using some command line options may reduce it more: `ruby -naF[,-] -e 'p (Time.new(*$F[0,3])-Time.new(*$F[3,3])).div 86400' <<< '2015-10-11,2015-07-11'` is 59 characters as I count it.

Comment: @manatwork Not sure if that is allowed.

Comment: The rule is that the minimum necessity needed to pass the code (in case of Ruby `-e`) is free, everything else has to be included in the count. There are different opinions on what exactly is that everything else. For example some members include the option separator space character and quotes around parameter values. In my view should only be counted what actually gets passed to the interpreter, extra characters required by shell syntax not. But can't remember any voice raised to disallow the use of options.

Comment: @manatwork Got it. Updated the answer.

Comment: almost not worth mentioning, but you can shave a byte by moving the repeated code into a proc: `t=->l{Time.gm(*$F[l,3])};p (t[0]-t[3]).div 86400`

Comment: @DaneAndersen, it certainly worth. And with your proc another character can be spared by removing the parenthesis around `Time.gm`'s parameter. Good catch. I only tried to use proc in an earlier phase when it was not yet feasible.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 63 bytes

Tested in chrome.

```
alert(((p=Date.parse)((a=prompt().split`,`)[0])-p(a[1]))/864e5)
```

Comment: comma-seperated from the question

Comment: @ev3commander Yes, I just fixed that.

Comment: I wonder why it works on Chrome but not on Firefox.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I've never actually tested this in firefox.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Huh. Firefox gives _Invalid date_, whilst chrome happily proceeds.

Comment: I'd mark this Chrome-specific as it *only* seems to work in chrome. I think the compliant way would be to use `Date.parse` and replace the `-` with `/`

Comment: works fine in chrome

Comment: Weird, I get an NaN error as the return from the alert, and the console says undefined in the console. (Thats on MS Edge). Chrome works fine though like everyone else is saying.

Comment: Most browsers require the date to be padded so `2015-12-03` will work but `2015-12-3` will not (except in Chrome). The question does say that the date will be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` so if the input really did follow that it would be cross-browser compatible, however the examples seem to say otherwise. Anyway, you could use `Date.parse` instead of `new Date` to save 2 bytes: ``alert((p((a=prompt(p=Date.parse).split`,`)[0])-p(a[1]))/864e5)``

Comment: @user81655 `Uncaught TypeError: p is not a function`. Attempting alternate restructure. Edit: Okay, I found a way that works.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Try this one (62 bytes): ``alert((a=prompt(p=Date.parse).split`,`,p(a[0])-p(a[1]))/864e5)``

Comment: @user81655 Sorry for the confusion. Now it says 2015-12-03 instead of 2015-12-3

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 41 bytes

```
A=K$.parse)(($B=Uq',  g0)-$A($Bg1))/864e5
```

So far this is the best I can get it as all the variables and `$` and parenthesis really kill the byte count.

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=QT1LJC5wYXJzZSkoKCRCPVVxJywgIGcwKS0kQSgkQmcxKSkvODY0ZTU=&input=IjIwMTUtMTItMDMsMjAxNS0xMi0wMSI=)

### Explanation

```
             // Implicit: U is set to input
A=K$.parse)  // Set variable A to date parsing function
(($B=Uq',    // Set B to input split by ,
  g0)        // Get the first date and parse
-            // Subtract...
$A(          // Parse this date...
   $Bg1      // Get's second date
))/864e5     // Divides by 86,400,000
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>41</s> 31 bytes

```
disp(-diff(datenum(input(''))))
{'2015-12-03', '2014-12-22'}
   346
```

Input must be a comma-separated cell array. `datenum` converts the input cell into a 2x1 numeric array with the time stamp. `diff` takes the difference between the two.

---

**Old solution, 41 bytes**:

```
disp(-diff(datenum(strsplit(input('')))))
```

Input must be a comma-separated string:

```
disp(-diff(datenum(strsplit(input('')))))
'2015-12-03, 2014-12-22'
   346
```

The curious ways of programming. This works because of MATLAB's implicit casting between datatypes.

The output from `strsplit(input(''))` is a cell of strings. You cannot use `diff` on a cell, but fortunately, `datenum` works, and it actually casts the cell input back to a 2x1 numeric array, making `diff` possible to use.

You can specify a whole lot of delimiters in `strsplit`, but comma is the default one. Also, the default input to `datenum` is on the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. For those reasons, a lot of specifications such as: datenum(s,'yyyy-mm-dd') are avoided, saving a whole lot of bytes.

For the record, this would be 21 bytes if I could use a function:

```
@(s)-diff(datenum(s))
```

Comment: How could I forget about diff... Might as well just delete my submission, because it's essentially the same, but with 2 calls to datenum instead.

Comment: Great choice of input format!

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 63 <s>64</s> <s>77</s> bytes

Found that the classic approach is shorter than the OOP one:

```
$x=fgetcsv(STDIN);$s=strtotime;echo($s($x[0])-$s($x[1]))/86400;
```

Reads the comma separated string from `STDIN`.

---

The straight forward OOP way (**77 bytes**):

```
$x=fgetcsv(STDIN);echo(new DateTime($x[0]))->diff(new DateTime($x[1]))->days;
```

---

**Edits**

- *Saved* **13 bytes** by using `strtotime` instead of `DateTime`.
- *Saved* **1 byte** by storing `strtotime` in a variable. Thanks to [Blackhole](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11713/blackhole).

Comment: -3 bytes: move the assignments to their first usage in parentheses (-1 byte each) and You can use `<?=` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 25 bytes

```
=LEFT(A1,10)-RIGHT(A1,10)
```

Excel automatically handles the strings as dates.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>109</s> 113 bytes

```
import datetime as d 
j=[d.date(*[int(k) for k in g.split('-')]) for g in raw_input().split(',')]
print j[0]-j[1]
```

Comment: The spaces between `)`s and `for`s are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 69 bytes

```
Function x(s)
g=Split(s, ",")
x=CDate(g(0))-CDate(g(1))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

## psql, 75 bytes

(74 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```sql
\prompt i
select split_part(:'i',',',1)::date-split_part(:'i',',',2)::date
```

`psql` is PostgreSQL's interactive terminal. To respect the “Each submission must be a full program.” rule, the code reads the input itself.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ psql -tf how-long-was-this.sql <<< '2015-12-3,2013-12-3'
      730
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>50</s> 44 Bytes

```
$a,$b=$args-split','|%{date $_};($a-$b).Days
```

Takes input argument as a string, splits it on the comma, then pipes the array via a built-in alias `date` short for `Get-Date` to convert our strings into .NET datetime format. Those two dates then get stored simultaneously into `$a` and `$b`. We then use an overloaded-subtraction-operator to subtract the second from the first, and output the `.Days` thereof.

Golfed 6 bytes thanks to [TessellatingHeckler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/571/tessellatingheckler).

Technically non-competing, as it doesn't have an online interpreter available, since the FOSS implementation of PowerShell, [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash), is around PowerShell v0.5. It doesn't support `-split` yet, let alone the complex .NET date functionality.

Answer (score 1):

### MATL, 5 bytes

```
iPYOd
```

This is the same as StewieGriffin's answer, except I used `flip` then `diff` rather than `diff` then negating the result.

Full explanation, with corresponding Matlab functions:

```
i   %// input(''), get input
P   %// flip, flips the array
YO  %// datenum, converts date string into an integer
d   %// diff, finds the difference between dates
```

Comment: Note: Whilst MATL was only released on December 12, after this challenge was posted, I came up with this answer on [December 9](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27409471#27409471) using a pre-release MATL compiler, which is almost identical to the released compiler, this code is the same.

Comment: Also, this is in no way an endorsement of the popular Apple portable music device :P

Comment: I should have used `o` for the `datenum` function :-D

Comment: That would have been amazing!

Comment: Does this handle leap years?

Comment: If the pre-release compiler is not public, this is invalid.

Comment: (I'm pretty sure this should be CW anyway because it's "*the same as StewieGriffin's answer*")

Comment: @ev3commander most answers on PPCG are the same as other answers, especially in cases like this where 4 commands suffice.

Comment: @David But you used a variant of the same language, etc...

Comment: This is invalid because of your first comment

Comment: Override header: invalid

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
£ÐXÃr- zHÑ7e5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o9BYw3ItIHpI0TdlNQ&input=WwoiMjAxNS0xMi0wMyIKIjIwMTUtMTItMDEiCl0)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>58</s> 53 bytes thanks to @targumon!

```js
n=>(new Date((a=n.split`,`)[0])-new Date(a[1]))/864e5
```

Older version:

```js
n=>(new Date((a=n.split(','))[0])-new Date(a[1]))/86400000
```

My submissions seem to have a reputation of being boring.

Comment: Let's push it down to 53 bytes:

`n=>(new Date((a=n.split\`,\`)[0])-new Date(a[1]))/864e5`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jolf](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=JFM9JHZpR2knLCBtRE5-REggcn0vbTRTbWVQIjg2NCI1), 33 bytes

Only works in Chrome. Noncompeting, since language updates postdate question. I'll add a more thorough explanation later.

```
$S=$viGi', mDN~DH r}/m4SmeP"864"5
```

### “Explanation”

```
$S=$viGi', mDN~DH r}
$S=$                 sets S equal to
    viGi',           take string input and reassign it to the comma-split input
           mD      } map with this function 
             N~DH r  return the time of the date of H (element)

/m4SmeP"864"5
/             divide
 m4S           subtraction applied to S (S[0] - S[1])
    meP"864"5  and 864 * 10 ^ 5 (thanks to Super Jedi for his nice constant)
              implicit output
```

Comment: How about you put "noncompeting" in your header?

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 59 bytes

```
s=strsplit(input(''),',');disp(datenum(s{1})-datenum(s{2}))
```

Very straightforward approach: input has to be given as a string from the command window. The input string is then split and the number of days between the dates (and nothing else) is calculated from the serial date numbers.
I'm quite sure there is a way to avoid the need for calling datenum twice though...

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 50 bytes

(49 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
./","|map(.+"T0:0:0Z"|fromdate)|(.[0]-.[1])/86400
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ~/bin/jq -R './","|map(.+"T0:0:0Z"|fromdate)|(.[0]-.[1])/86400' <<< '2015-12-3,2013-12-3'
730
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=./%22,%22|map%28.%2B%22T0:0:0Z%22|fromdate%29|%28.[0]-.[1]%29/86400&j=%222015-12-3,2013-12-3%22) (Passing `-R` through URL is not supported – so input passed as string "2015-12-3,2013-12-3".)

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL + SQLCMD, 51 bytes

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(D,RIGHT('$(i)',10),LEFT('$(i)',10))
```

Tested with SQL Server 2008R2.  The $(i) is replaced with the input provided as a command line argument.

Sample run:

```
sqlcmd -i script.sql -v i="2015-12-08,2016-01-01"
-24
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, <strike>91</strike> 86 + 2 for np flags, 88 bytes

<strike>use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days);($a,$b)=split(/,/);$_=Delta_Days(split(/-/,$b),split(/-/,$a))</strike>

```
use Date::Parse;$_=str2time((split(/,/,$_))[0])-str2time((split(/,/,$_))[1]);$_/=86400
```

Example

```
$ echo 2015-12-3,2015-12-1 | perl -npe 'use Date::Parse;$_=str2time((split(/,/,$_))[0])-str2time((split(/,/,$_))[1]);$_/=86400'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
Print@First[#-#2&@@DateObject/@InputString[]~StringSplit~","]
```

Basic date subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
Print@#&@@-DateDifference@@InputString[]~StringSplit~","
```

Most (all?) date functions will try to parse string inputs into dates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 148 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){Console.Write((DateTime.Parse(a[0].Substring(11,10))-DateTime.Parse(a[0].Substring(0,10))).Days);}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##fcuxCoMwEIDhV8mYgAmJUGhxrGtBsNBBHK5pKAeagHcWRHz2VOre7R@@35P25HOeCeNbtAtxGCs/AJFoVmJg9OKT8CVugFESTzvrelDrNUVKQzCPCTlIWQOHO47BNDBRkNDZ3rTz8xikc4WzSun/yv6QMjUspKptyzmX1l20PenSFUee9/wC)

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <s>225</s> 199 bytes

-25 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)! Replacing an array of numbers with a string of wide-characters is some proper black-magic

-1 byte by adding an additional character to the start of the string, allowing for indexing with [m] instead of [m-1]

```
a,b,d,e,f;i(m,y){return(a=y-1)*365+a/4-a/100+a/400+L"\0\37;Zx\x97µÔóđİŎ"[m]+(m>1&(y%100*!(y%4)||y%400<1));}main(c){scanf("%d-%d-%d,%d-%d-%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);printf("%d",i(b,a)-i(e,d)+c-f);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYttisIwGISvogFDXvu@mNSPEqp7Ak@w1h9p2kp@tEhVsKhXEBY8iCB7AT/OVbPCwjDzwMxYWlnbtgZTzDDHInaixAYOdb7d1ZUws4YU9IeTcWAGIzIDJeUfeZ@zTiKTYRR/75O9ju6/j8vj9vx5Xl9ntiiXgSi/FBdNzz/6XZ8jOB69SzlVAPGpNK4SFg4ba6pCsF5GH@E/MOQGeYrcIs@Q58gLiNe1q7afNUMnUjRATuSYQWDJ16e2DaUKSUakQlRaa5@k9Bs)

Perhaps the code could be shortened by using <time.h>, but not using it makes for a fun challenge.
The difference between dates is calculated using a golfed version of [this code](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/datediffindays/calcdiffofdatesindates.html).

Un-golfed:

```
a,b,d,e,f;
i(m,y){
    return(a=y-1)*365 /*Num days in y-1 years*/
        +a/4-a/100+a/400 /*Add previous years' leap days*/
        +L" \0\37;Zx\x97µÔóđİŎ"[m] /*Add days this year until month*/
        +(m>1&(y%100*!(y%4)||y%400<1)); /*Add this year's leap day*/
}
main(c){
    scanf("%d-%d-%d,%d-%d-%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);
    printf("%d",i(b,a)-i(e,d)+c-f);
}
```